# How To Run Python Code With Visual Studio Environment Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019

I am running my python codes vith visual studio 2019 community edition.

When I run my code with visual studio it is working fine.
In Visual Studio when i run my code : *C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\python.exe* is running fine.

But when i run directly *'C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\python.exe'* and then running that script :

```
exec(open("C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\PytIn\proj\code.py").read())
```

After that i am getting error like that:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "<string>", line 4, in <module> File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module> "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies) ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy: DLL load failed:The specified module could not be found.`

Could be any chance VisualStudio and Python.exe using different directories for loaded libraries?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? As an aside, you shouldn't use the default Anaconda Python installation for development.

Comment: I want to create quick bat file for execution the app without packacing the app. Actually visual studio using that direction automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio and what you refer to as direct execution may indeed be looking in two different places for library packages. When you run python directly, or from the command line, it looks for packages in C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages. When you use Visual Studio, it looks in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\site-packages. There are two possible solutions, install the packages in both places, which is redundant, but works for sure, or point your environment variables in visual studio to the AppData packages, which works until you need to update a package via your visual studio envioronment.